# Nearest user search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

If I had lat/long info about the user. 
What's more efficient/scalable way to look-up a nearest n users near user x ordered by distance or something else.

I can think of two ways to do this :

1. Geocoder gem, handling search on web server level
2. Using postgres database with postgis, handling search on db level

However I'm struggling to evaluate these options correctly. The reason for that is web server/database cache, so I don't really see the times always correct.

Which one of these two is a better solution in following terms of lookup speed impact(does it scale)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the geocoder gem implements the second option.

Comment: @japed no you don't have to have the postgis extension to be able to use the geocoder gem

Comment: I know, but what it implements is bascially what you're describing in 2.

Comment: no it's not. number 2 is using the postgres postgis capabilities, i.e st_distance and other functions. And the geocoder gem does calculations in the code and not at the db level. geocoder gem does not take advantage of those geospatial capabilities of postgres

Comment: Where do you want your slowdown to occur? On the front-end in your web server or on the backend in the database? The front-end could impact everyone. The backend, if you use a separate database and server, would only impact actions requiring that lookup.

Comment: @theTinMan that's a very good observation. But I would rather impact the web server, because web servers load balancing is more convenient to setup right. You just take a few instances of your app up on individual instances (could be the same of different server), use the load balancer to distribute the requests with no or little change to your application (sticky sessions perhaps). So I'd rather slowdown occur on the web server. What do you think

Comment: Load balancing won't help individual users who have a connection established if that delay affects the rendering of a page's HTML. If it's a separate resource being required by the page, then yes, load-balancing would help. Only you know what you're going to be returning so you have to keep that stuff in mind.